# Installing vector pkg using cabal fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

I try to install vector package using `cabal install vector` but it fails giving the error here: http://hastebin.com/miwunadefo.vbs
My cabal version is:

```
bd$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1.2 of the Cabal library
```

GHC:

```
bd$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

GCC:

```
bd$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: What is your `ghc` version?

Comment: Which operating system? This looks a bit like the errors MacOS X gives if you only have Clang installed and no GCC.

Comment: GHC version 7.6.3, Apple LLVM version 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Some packages require GCC for compiling C-code or expanding C-like preprocessor pragmas. [The MacOSX page on the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Mac_OS_X) has more information as the exact solution depends on your specific OSX version.